# validate uniqueness amongst multiple subclasses with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I have a Card model that has many CardSets and a CardSet model that has many Cards through a Membership model:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :card_sets, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :card_set

  validates_uniqueness_of :card_id, :scope => :card_set_id
end

class CardSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :cards, :through => :memberships

  validates_presence_of :cards
end
```

I also have some sub-classes of the above using Single Table Inheritance:

```
class FooCard < Card
end

class BarCard < Card
end
```

and

```
class Expansion < CardSet
end

class GameSet < CardSet
  validates_size_of :cards, :is => 10
end
```

All of the above is working as I intend.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to validate that a Card can only belong to a single Expansion.  I want the following to be invalid:

```
some_cards = FooCard.all( :limit => 25 )

first_expansion = Expansion.new
second_expansion = Expansion.new

first_expansion.cards = some_cards
second_expansion.cards = some_cards

first_expansion.save    # Valid
second_expansion.save   # **Should be invalid**
```

However, GameSets should allow this behavior:

```
other_cards = FooCard.all( :limit => 10 )

first_set = GameSet.new
second_set = GameSet.new

first_set.cards = other_cards    # Valid
second_set.cards = other_cards   # Also valid
```

I'm guessing that a validates_uniqueness_of call is needed somewhere, but I'm not sure where to put it.  Any suggestions?

### UPDATE 1

I modified the Expansion class as sugested:

```
class Expansion < CardSet 
  validate :validates_uniqueness_of_cards

  def validates_uniqueness_of_cards
    membership = Membership.find(
      :first,
      :include => :card_set,
      :conditions => [
        "card_id IN (?) AND card_sets.type = ?",
        self.cards.map(&:id), "Expansion"
      ]
    )
    errors.add_to_base("a Card can only belong to a single Expansion") unless membership.nil?
  end
end
```

This works!  Thanks J.!

### Update 2

I spoke a little too soon.  The above solution was working great until I went to update an Expansion with a new card.  It was incorrectly identifying subsequent `#valid?` checks as false because it was finding itself in the database.  I fixed this by adding a check for `#new_record?` in the validation method:

```
class Expansion < CardSet
  validate :validates_uniqueness_of_cards

  def validates_uniqueness_of_cards
    sql_string = "card_id IN (?) AND card_sets.type = ?"
    sql_params = [self.cards.map(&:id), "Expansion"]

    unless new_record?
      sql_string << " AND card_set_id <> ?"
      sql_params << self.id
    end

    membership = Membership.find(
                   :first,
                   :include => :card_set,
                   :conditions => [sql_string, *sql_params]
                 )

    errors.add_to_base("a Card can only belong to a single Expansion") unless membership.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *really* not sure about that, I'm just trying because I'm not able to test it here... but maybe something like the following works for you. Let me know if it does :]

```
class Expansion < Set 
   validate :validates_uniqueness_of_cards

   def validates_uniqueness_of_cards
      membership = Membership.find(:first, :include => :set,
         :conditions => ["card_id IN (?) AND set.type = ?",
            self.cards.map(&:id), "Expansion"])
      errors.add_to_base("Error message") unless membership.nil?
   end
end
```

Comment: I'm going to test adding `validates_uniqueness_of :card_ids` to the Expansion class when I get home.  Could it be that simple?  (on an unrelated note: trying to update a comment on StackOverflow with your iphone is a terrible idea!  They really need to implement a mobile view for this site!)

Comment: nope.  My idea didn't work.  I've got access to Rails now, I'll experiment some with you idea.

Comment: Thanks again, J.  I updated my question with my final validation method.  I had to add a check so an Expansion would ignore itself in future `#update`s, but other than that you're solution was perfect.

Comment: I completely forgot this `update` case. But I'm glad my answer helped you :]

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party here, but assuming you've set up STI, then you can now validate uniqueness of an attribute scoped to the sti type,

e.g

validates_uniqueness_of :your_attribute_id, scope: :type