# Rails 3 Change Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have an error message that appears when my the field for the database `:b_name` is empty. However, `b_name` stands for Business Name and I have made the label say that. However, when I get the error message, it says `B name` cant be blank. Is there any way I can change it so when I get the error it says `Business Name can't be blank` instead of `b_name cant be blank`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is actually really simple.

You should have a file named config/locales/en.yml, if not simply create one. There you can add your own custom names.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      order:            "Order"
    attributes:
      order:
        b_name:         "Business Name"
```

That will replace your b_name for "Business Name"

Your Order model in app/models/order.rb should look like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :b_name, :presence => true
  .
  . 
  .
```

Please let me know if it worked :)

Here is an screenshot of my app working fine.
[image: Here is an screenshot of my app working]

Comment: Its not working but maybe I'm doing something wrong. My model name is Order so heres what mine looked like.

Comment: en: 
  models:
    model_name: "Order"
  attributes:
    model_name:
      b_name: "Business Name"
      other_attr: "Other Name"

Comment: i think what i have to do is in my application controller do before_filter :set_locale and make a function set_locale. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Ups my bad, it should be nested under active record, let me fix it. It should work now :)

Comment: i'm not getting an error but I'm not getting success. It still says B name can't be blank. Any thoughts?

Comment: The yaml file is tab sensitive, so you should be sure that your file is indented correctly, just as shown on the code above. I created a new Rails application to replicate your situation and it is working for me, let my share you my code :)

Comment: I encourage you to put the tabs exactly as mines.

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't know the tabs were case sensitive like that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `:message` validation option, it's common to all [validation methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have something like this in your model

`validates_presence_of :b_name`

If you want to change the message printed when this validation fails you can use the `:message` option

`validates_presence_of :b_name, :message => 'some other message'` unfortunately this will still print the field name. The message will be 'B name some other message'

To get around it see this other SO question.

[Using Rails validation helpers :message but want it without listing the column name in message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690267/using-rails-validation-helpers-message-but-want-it-without-listing-the-column-na)

From [this](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/12/change-displayed-column-name-in-rails-validation-messages) post The easiest method is to add a `human_attribute_name` method like so,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :b_name => "Business Name"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

end
```

Comment: so how would i do validates_presence_of :b_name now? would it be like validates_presence_of human_attribute_name("b_name") ?

Comment: No the validated presence of call wouldn't change

Comment: I get an error saying wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) on line #3. `<h2><%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>`