# Custom Validation message in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

When I use the following validation:

```
 validates_length_of :lgtitle, :maximum=>45, :message=>"Please reduce the number of characters used in the Before Like Title. The maximum is 45 characters."
```

Rails returns the message and the table row in my view:

```
Lgtitle Please reduce the number of characters used in the Before Like Title. The maximum is 45 characters.
```

What is the best practice for eliminating the table table row string that is added to the validation message?

Thank you.

Comment: There was a similar question few time ago. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690267/using-rails-validation-helpers-message-but-want-it-without-listing-the-column-na

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error messages are added in `model.errors` which is a `Hash`.

- Keys are column names
- Values, the message itself

I bet you display both key and value.